# Creating small backend to manage Firebase data with Javascript API

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, frameworks, backend

I have an iOS and Android App using Firebase as database and I need to create a small backend to display all the firebase data in web and change some of the values. The one for which I develop the app is not capable of doing any of these changes directly in Firebase backend.

So should I create my own small backend with Javascript API or are there any frameworks or other solutions for this?

Comment: What kind of data are we talking about ?
You could download the firebase database as a json file and then adjust it ?!